# Visual graph representation of the branches of plot in the game for Android

Tags: android, java

I am implementing the visual graph representation for the branches of plot in the game for Android platform. I implemented graph by myself and I need a library for drawing paths between nodes of the graph that contains choices that will lead to particular consequences or to other choices. It will show to users their progress and unlocked paths. Actually, I want this graph to be similar to representation of branches in the game Detroit: Becoming Human. Screenshot would be attached below.

Updated: By path I mean lines. I tried do it by canvas, but it looks ugly, is there library to draw such lines between particular points. In my case it is nodes of graph. It would be even better if you will suggest the library for drawing visual representation of graph.

[image: otlin]

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements.